# Flatlist row with items of different size

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using a flatlist to create a grid of items containing images, videos, blogs and audios. There are two columns in the flatlist. I have added a button to add dummy posts in flatlist. Problem is the height of items. When i add a blog in flatlist , it has text, images in it and item beside it . i.e image or video also gets the height of the blog item. Is it possible to give variable height to every item in row. On adding blog to the flatlist video item has also taken height qual to the blog item.

[image: screen shot of problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this library to create a Masonry list.
https://github.com/AppAndFlow/react-native-masonry-list .It works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

According to [official document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#numcolumns), when flatlist has multy cols, `Items should all be the same height - masonry layouts are not supported.`

But I think you can try to add a wrapper `View` on each column item to avoid this rule. The flatlist's `height` will be set on the wrapper, your item's height can still config by you.

Comment: I will try and get back to you

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your reply, I am able to change height. But now there is another problem , there is space below the item if item beside it has higher height.

Comment: That can't be fixed because of the rule I just mentioned. I think you should try some 3rd party lib. this lib may meet your request. [react-native-masonry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-masonry)

Comment: I think this library only works with Images. I have a various types of components i.e image, video, blog, audio.

Answer (score -1):

Interestingly enough, this can be achieved without any external libraries. The trick is to use negative margin.

The implementation is slightly tricky - We need to apply the negative margin in the VirtualizedList prop CellRendererComponent in order to get it to work properly on Android.

The JSX:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        style={styles.flatlist}
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        CellRendererComponent={({ children, item, ...props }) => {
            return (
                <View {...props} style={{ marginTop: item.marginTop }}>
                    {children}
                </View>
            )
        }}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
            const { source: source1, height: height1, marginTop: marginTop1 } = item.image1;
            const { source: source2, height: height2, marginTop: marginTop2 } = item.image2;
            return (
                <View style={Style.viewRow}>
                    <Image source={source1} style={[styles.image, { height: height1, marginTop: marginTop1 }]} />
                    <Image source={source2} style={[styles.image, { height: height2, marginTop: marginTop2 }]} />
                </View>
            )
        }}
    />
</View>
```

The data:

```
const source = { uri: 'https://placekitten.com/160/300' };

const data = [
    {
        marginTop: 0,
        image1: { source, height: 300, marginTop: 0 },
        image2: { source, height: 250, marginTop: 0 }
    },
    {
        marginTop: -50,
        image1: { source, height: 290, marginTop: 50 },
        image2: { source, height: 300, marginTop: 0 }
    },
    {
        marginTop: -40,
        image1: { source, height: 250, marginTop: 40 },
        image2: { source, height: 350, marginTop: 0 }
    }
];
```

The styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
      flex: 1
   },
   flatList: {
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%'
   },
   viewRow: {
      flexDirection: 'row'
   },
   image: {
      width: '50%',
      resizeMode: 'cover'
   }
});
```

Make sure to arrange the data of the images in the array properly - always place the taller image in the shorter side, calculate the difference of height, and so on.